# Two dimensional array giving incorrect result in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have this code to create 2d array by loop

```
result = dict()
final = dict()

with open(self.json_file , 'w') as outfile:
    for entry in sections_list:
        path_items = raw_config.items(entry)
        for key,path in path_items:
            final[key]=path
            result[entry] = final
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```

but in result i got all key, path for each entry !
What to do ???

Comment: That is what you are assigning, you assign `final[key]=path` and then `result[entry] = final` what do you expect to happen? You are also creating two dicts not a 2d array.

Comment: You only have one `final` dict, and you use it for everything. Also, you probably ought to [read up on Python's data structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/), because dicts aren't arrays.

Comment: ok. how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, I think you want a dict contains dict elements, you can do it like this:

```
result = dict()
with open(self.json_file , 'w') as outfile:
    for entry in sections_list:
        path_items = raw_config.items(entry)
        result[entry] = dict()
        for key,path in path_items:
            result[entry][key] = path

    json.dump(result, outfile)
```

If `path_items` is a list/tuple of list/tuple which contains two elements, you can make the code simpler like this:

```
result = dict()
with open(self.json_file , 'w') as outfile:
    for entry in sections_list:
        path_items = raw_config.items(entry)
        result[entry] = dict(path_items)

    json.dump(result, outfile)
```